# Search page with friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, mod-rewrite

I have a search form on my site

```
<form class="clearfix" action="search.php" method="get">
                <h1>Search the Site</h1>
                <input class="field" type="text" name="q" id="query" value="" size="23" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="bt_login" />
</form>
```

right now it posts to search.php, but I want it to post to /search/query-here. My .htaccess file looks like this right now

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=404

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^(products|blog|feed|search|checkout|checkout)$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule products/cat/(.*)$ products.php?type=cat&cat=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule products/(.*)$ products.php?type=single&product=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog.php&post=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule feed/(.*) feed.phptype=$1 [nc]

RewriteRule search\.php?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?wghandcrafted.com/.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|psd|js|swf|flv|png)$ /feed/ [R=302]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^images/.*\.jpg$ /images/default.jpg [L]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what GET string are you getting when the form submits?

Comment: the form sends the get "q" for query. It posts the get to search.php which works, but it needs to be /search/query

Comment: Shouldn't the `?`-character be escaped in the 301-redirect RewriteRule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the way to do this, could be to

1. Detect the form has been submitted
2. Use the header() function to redirect the user to the correct URL.
3. Let the .htaccess file rewrite the URL in the background
4. Process the form if the correct variable name is given

This would likely be seamless and the user wouldn't know it had happened.

So...

Revised form with method="POST" and name="search_form"

```
<form class="clearfix" action="search.php" method="POST" name="search_form">
                <h1>Search the Site</h1>
                <input class="field" type="text" name="q" id="query" value="" size="23" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="bt_login" />
</form>
```

**.htaccess**
Get URL in the form of http://website.com/search/search+term and rewrite to http://website.com/search.php?q=search+term in the background

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST['search_form'])
{

    // Get the search query
    $search_query = $_POST['q'];

    header("Location: search/" . urlencode($search_query));
    exit();
}
else if ($_GET['q'])
{
    $query_from_url = $_GET['q'];

    echo "The query from the URL is" . $query_from_url;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited a tonne of mistakes.  It's untested, but if you have any trouble, just post it here.

Comment: Why do you use PHP for the first rewrite? It would be faster to also do it in `.htaccess`, because the PHP-interprenter doesn't need to be loaded.

Comment: @andre_roesti I'm not aware of a way to get the variables in to the URL unfortunately

Comment: I'm not completely certain, but I think that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650479](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650479) is an example of the same thing, because it will need access to the database and you can't do that from .htaccess.  See how it prepends the URL with the name of the post

Comment: Thank you! That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove or comment out this line:

```
RewriteRule search\.php?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and then get the form to submit to its self,on the search.php page take the variables and build the string you want and then use:

`header("location:search/nice+string")`

Comment: that wont help. basically what I need to do is redirect search.php?q=query to /search/query.